# Sum of the digits of $10^{30} - 90$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

When $10^{30}-90$ is written in full, what is the sum of the digits?

Comment: What are the digits which compose 10^30 ?

Comment: No, I need the sum of all the digits in the number if it is evaluated.

Comment: Yes ! answer this first.

Comment: Umm, 1 and 30 zeroes after it.

Comment: Now, you have the hint from tomasz.

Comment: I get it now! Is the answer 253?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: What is the sum of digits of $10^n-9\cdot10^m$, where $m<n$ are natural numbers?

Comment: Is it 9(n-m-1) + 1 ?

Comment: @AnishBhattacharya: Yes. You can check directly that $10^n-9\cdot10^m=10^m+\sum_{j={m+1}}^{n-1}9\cdot 10^j$.

Comment: Okay. Thanks tomasz !!